# Winston logger filename error undefined

Tags: node.js, logging, undefined, winston

i am new to node js and was trying winston logger for my project,everything works properly but when i am trying to create my own logger object and transport the logs to file name i am getting error as : **TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined** 
I feel i have done anything silly because when i simply try to write the logs to file using winston default object it works,i am posting my code with snapshots of error.

I created simple express js project and whote  the logging code in app.js as follows :

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express'), routes = require('./routes'), user = require('./routes/user'), http = require('http'), path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

// adding winston logger code--------------------
var winston = require('winston');
/*
 * winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'winstonLogs.log' });
 * 
 * winston.log('info', 'Hello distributed log files!'); winston.info('Hello
 * again distributed logs');
 * 
 * winston.level = 'debug'; winston.log('debug', 'Now my debug messages are
 * written to console!');
 * 
 * //winston.remove(winston.transports.Console);
 */
// ******************************************************************************


var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
      transports: [
        new (winston.transports.File)({
          name: 'info-file',
          filename: 'filelog-info.log',
          level: 'info'
        }),
        new (winston.transports.File)({
          name: 'error-file',
          filename: 'filelog-error.log',
          level: 'error'
        })
      ]
    });
logger.add(winston.transports.File);


logger.log('info', 'Hello distributed log files!');
logger.info('Hello again distributed logs');

//logger.add(winston.transports.File).remove(winston.transports.Console);

// ending winston logger code--------------------

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

The code which i have commented out is working.[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Actually i added the line which was not supposed to be there.

```
logger.add(winston.transports.File);
```

After removing it it started working fine...